# How to pass two JSON list of a response to another feature file

Tags: json, karate

I have to pass 2 list to a read function but I can't. I tried many things but I don't fine the solution.
Here is what I have done

#step 1

```
    * url callPathProvider = anything
    Given url callPath
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

#retrieve specific values

```
      * def array1 = ...
```

#for this part I refer to *[How to pass the json list response of one feature file as parameter to another feature file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54302339/how-to-pass-the-json-list-response-of-one-feature-file-as-parameter-to-another-f)*

```
     * def data1 = karate.map(array1, function(x){ return { channelDefId: x } })
     * print data1
```

result of the print :

```
    [
      {"channelDefId":"201"},
      {"channelDefId":"301"},
      {"channelDefId":"401"},
      {"channelDefId":"501"}
      ...
    ]
```

```
      * def array2 = array1.map(x => x.replace('01', '') * 1)
      * def data2 = karate.map(array2, function(x){ return { listOfId: x } })
      * print data2
```

result of the print :

```
   [
    {"listOfId":2},
    {"listOfId":3},
    {"listOfId":4},
    {"listOfId":5}
    ...
    ]
```

#step 2

```
    * def result = call read('called.feature')(data2, data1)
```

```
=> this is not working, I got
```

feature call loop failed at index: 0, js failed:
01: [ listOfId, 'channel_definitions', channelDefId, 'authorize_url']
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "channelDefId" is not defined .:program(Unnamed:1)

And `called.feature` is:

```
   Feature:

   Scenario:
    Given url 'part1'
    And path  listOfId, 'part2', channelDefId, 'part3'
    When method POST
    Then status 201
```

I tried with one list like :
* def result = call read('called.feature') data1
or
* def result = call read('called.feature') data2
And it was working as supposed to be

Comment: my first thought is that you are un-necessarily complicating things. if you can simplify (edit) your question to be clear about what you are actually trying to do, that would help others answer it. meanwhile see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+call+argument

Answer (score 0):

I delete this part of my main file

- def array2 = array1.map(x => x.replace('01', '') * 1)
- def data2 = karate.map(array2, function(x){ return { listOfId: x } })

and add this one in file called.feature:

- def listOfId = xx.replace('01', '')

This isn't what I want but it working.

If someone know how to do this :
def result = call read('called.feature') list1 list2

Alicya